# Android: To get a image from server

Tags: android, listview, bitmap

I used a ListView which contains a ImageView and a TextView. I want to get a image from server. I debug the code below, which told me that I can get the image successful, but when return, the image disappeared. I don't know why. I am the new begginner of android. Hope anyone can help me.

The ListView Adapter class:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    News news = getItem(position); 
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(resourceId, null);
    newsImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.news_image);
    newsTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.news_title);

    newsTitle.setText(news.getTitle());
    bitmap = HttpUtil.sendImageRequest(news.getImageUrl());
    newsImage.setImageBitmap(ImageUtility.ImageSolution(bitmap, newsImage));
    return view;
}
```

the sendImageRequest method:

```
public static Bitmap sendImageRequest(final String address){
    final Bitmap[] bitmap = new Bitmap[1];
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            HttpURLConnection connection = null;
            try {
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(address).openConnection();
                connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                connection.setDoInput(true);

                InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();
                bitmap[0] = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (connection != null){
                    connection.disconnect();
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
    return bitmap[0];
}
```

the ImageSolution method:

```
public static Bitmap ImageSolution (Bitmap bitmap, ImageView imageView){
    int width = bitmap.getWidth();
    int height = bitmap.getHeight();
    int newWidth = imageView.getWidth();
    int newHeight = imageView.getHeight();

    float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
    float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;

    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);

    Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, width,
            height, matrix, true);
    return resizedBitmap;
}
```

the address is http://p2.zhimg.com/10/7b/107bb4894b46d75a892da6fa80ef504a.jpg.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
bitmap = HttpUtil.sendImageRequest(news.getImageUrl());
```

bitmap will always be empty as it is an image request. The function starts a thread but returns immediately. So returns an empty bitmap.

```
newsImage.setImageBitmap(ImageUtility.ImageSolution(bitmap, newsImage));
```

If you then try to set that empty bitmap to an imageview things go wrong.

Redesign your app. Only when the thread finishes there is a valid bitmap. And then you can use it.

Comment: I don't know much about it. So if I want to return the bitmap, what should I do? or can I use AsyncTask to get the bitmap from server, and then refresh the UI? where should I put the AsyncTask class?

Comment: The easiest solution is to use runOnUIThread to place the bitmap in the imageview. Do that in the run() of your thread when the bitmap is there. As last statement.

Comment: Thank you so much. I solved the problem. I used the HttpCallbackListener.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a third party library named [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)  , which is recommended by google . To add this library , add the the following dependency in your build.gradle file , in module app .

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.5.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'
}
```

And then you can simply load image in following way

```
Glide.with(context)
    .load(news.getImageUrl())
    .into(newsImage);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso) library?

It's really easy to use

```
Picasso.with(context).load(news.getImageUrl()).into(newsImage);
```

And it provides caching and image transformations.

Answer (score 0):

Make a viewHolder class inside adapter class,

```
private static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView newsTitle = null;
    public ImageView newsImage = null;
}
```

then code your getView like,

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final ViewHolder itemHolder;
    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        itemHolder = new ViewHolder();
        view = inflater.inflate(layoutResID, parent, false);

        itemHolder.newsImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.news_image);
        itemHolder.newsTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.news_title);


        view.setTag(itemHolder);
    } else {
        itemHolder = (viewHolder) view.getTag();
    }

    News news = getItem(position);

    itemHolder.newsTitle.setText(news.getTitle());
    bitmap = HttpUtil.sendImageRequest(news.getImageUrl());
    itemHolder.newsImage.setImageBitmap(ImageUtility.ImageSolution(bitmap, newsImage));


    return view;
}
```

or, you can use picasso, it is easy to use...

add this line inside dependencies,

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.0'
```

and for loading image code for loading image will be,

```
Picasso.with(context).load(news.getImageUrl()).into(itemHolder.newsImage);
```

Comment: Viewholder or not. The bitmap is empty. You did not resolve the problem.